# "Your Apple ID has been disabled."

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm trying to test iOS StoreKit in-app purchases on my device. I've created a test user in iTunesConnect and logged out of the App Store. I open my app, click Buy, and then I'm prompted for my test user's Apple ID and password. I type those in, and I get an error dialog that says "Your Apple ID has been disabled."

I've tried using iForgot to reset my test user's password; no help.

Why is this happening? What do I do about it?

Comment: I think you should address this question to Apple customer support, it's not really related to programming imo...

Comment: Apple developer support, you mean? It's an iTunesConnect test user sandbox problem; Apple customer support can't help. (I suppose I could pay for an Apple dev support ticket, but I was hoping stackoverflow could help me first!)

Comment: Why is this closed. Dealing with iTunes connect is a part of programmers' work, and there are many questions on the topic on stackoverflow.